# Connect to elasticsearch in google app engine through java transport client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, elasticsearch

I want to connect to *Elasticsearch* cluster in *Google AppEngine* through java [TransportClient](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html). But the AppEngine sandbox settings prevent me from creating *TransportClient* since it employs thread pooling. Is there a way to enable thread pooling in my app?

Comment: Added link to TransportClient docs and used appropriate CamelCase for product names

Comment: Hi, You will have to fall back to the rest interface here